# Jquery Add Argument to Function on $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, arguments

I want to return my button value if ajax failure.

This HTML (on PHP):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="follow-topic" value="7">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary pull-right"><?php echo $_LANGS['forum']['follow']; ?></button>
</a>
```

This JS (on PHP):

```
    $("#follow-topic").click(function(event) {
        var topicid = $(this).attr('value');
        var button_follow_html = $(this).html();
        if ($(this).is("a[disabled]")){ return false; }
        $("#follow-topic button").html('<?php echo $_LANGS['system']['loading_button']; ?>');
        $(this).attr({ disabled: true});
        $.ajax({
            url: "",
            data: { follow_topic: topicid },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#follow-topic").html(data);
                $("#follow-topic").attr({ disabled: false});
            },
            error: function(data, button_follow_html) {
                handleRequestError(data);
                $("#follow-topic").attr({ disabled: false});
                $("#follow-topic").html(button_follow_html);
            }
        });
    });
```

I've change a button value to `$_LANGS['system']['loading_button']` but i want return to `$_LANGS['forum']['follow']` if ajax failure or client lost connection.

This system using multiple languages and if ajax is success, button will be replaced to followed button so i can't use `$("#follow-topic button").html('<?php echo $_LANGS['forum']['follow']; ?>');`.

Sorry for My English and Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/), the `error` function called if ajax call fails takes 3 parameters:

> error
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

So you are actually getting the `textStatus` respond in your `button_follow_html` variable in this code:

```
        error: function(data, button_follow_html) {
            handleRequestError(data);
            $("#follow-topic").attr({ disabled: false});
            $("#follow-topic").html(button_follow_html);
        }
```

The parameters are optionnal, so instead you can just do:

```
        error: function(data) {
            handleRequestError(data);
            $("#follow-topic").attr({ disabled: false});
            $("#follow-topic").html(button_follow_html);
        }
```

`button_follow_html` won't be redefined and will still have the same value as before the ajax call so you can use it as is.